# How to correctly order my containers in a responsive Bootstrap page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out how to set the order of my containers in a page so that they will correctly reorder themselves in both mobile and desktop layouts when resized.

Here is my code, the order is correct here in tablet [col-sm] & and phone [col-xs] views:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>

        div {border:1px solid #000;}

        div.logo {background:transparent url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat left top; height:100px;}

        div.rider {height:50px;background-color:#06C;}

        div.search {height:50px;background-color:#F39;}

        div.headers {height:100px;background-color:#933;}

        div.navigation1 {height:300px;background-color:#69F;}

        div.content {height:600px;background-color:#0FC;}

        div.social {height:50px;background-color:#C99;}

        div.navigation2 {height:300px;background-color:#3FF;}

        div.footer {height:150px;background-color:#000;}        

        </style>

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-md-12 logo"></div>          

            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">

                <div class="rider">rider</div>

                <div class="search">search</div>

                <div class="navigation1">1st Nav</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">

                <div class="headers">headers</div>

                <div class="content">content</div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">

                <div class="social">social</div>

                <div class="navigation2">2nd Nav</div>  

                <div class="footer">footer</div>

            </div>

        </div>

         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

The problem is for a desktop layout, there is a big gap under the 1st Nav div, the social div should be immediately beneath the 1st Nav in desktop and larger views regardless of the height of the content div.

How do I fix this? I tried using the pull, push, offset and float methods, but nothing gave me the correct results.

Comment: Working on an answer for you, but just a tip: You don't need to specify `col-xs-12`, as this is basically what it will default to if you do not specify anything for that size.

Answer (score 0):

The gap that you are talking about is actually not a gap in the solid left column. It is a gap between content in the left column of first row and the left column of the second row.

Your last wrapping div (social/nav2/footer) is in the second row, so it can touch the first wrapping div (rider/search/nav1) from below only if the height of second wrapping div (headers/content) is less than of first (which is definitely not an option here).

To fix the problem, I'd suggest to put contents of last wrapping div into first one. However it will break the order in mobile and tablet layouts.

As the second option I could offer to duplicate contents of last wrapping div to first one, but make it visible only in desktop screen sizes by using .visible-md and .visible-lg classes on upper instance and to show the one below only in mobile screens (use .hidden-md .hidden-lg classes). This is not the best idea from performance standpoint (extra traffic, extra server-side processing) but it could work.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
        div {border:1px solid #000;}
        div.logo {background:transparent url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat left top; height:100px;}
        div.rider {height:50px;background-color:#06C;}
        div.search {height:50px;background-color:#F39;}
        div.headers {height:100px;background-color:#933;}
        div.navigation1 {height:300px;background-color:#69F;}
        div.content {height:600px;background-color:#0FC;}
        div.social {height:50px;background-color:#C99;}
        div.navigation2 {height:300px;background-color:#3FF;}
        div.footer {height:150px;background-color:#000;}        
        </style>
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12 logo"></div>          
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                <div class="rider">rider</div>
                <div class="search">search</div>
                <div class="navigation1">1st Nav</div>
                <div class="visible-md visible-lg">
                  <div class="social">social</div>
                  <div class="navigation2">2nd Nav</div>  
                  <div class="footer">footer</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                <div class="headers">headers</div>
                <div class="content">content</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">
                <div class="social">social</div>
                <div class="navigation2">2nd Nav</div>  
                <div class="footer">footer</div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would have to agree, these are the only two options I can see working to accomplish the goal.